# Архитипы в maven

Tags: java, maven

Написал свое первое клиент серверное приложение. Собрал его через IDE. Сторонние библиотеки не использовал. Все работает без проблем.
Решил переделать приложение и упростить его с помощью библиотек. Начал изучать Maven. Написал файл pom.xml. Jar файл формируется, но программа не работает. Грешу на правильность написания pom.xml.
**Вопрос который стал на данные момент.** Не могу разобраться с архитипами. Я так понял это шаблоны. Но как выбрать нужный, где есть их описания?

Ссылка на проэкт: https://github.com/OnlyTarg/WIW-Server

вот мой pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

  <groupId>ONLYTARG</groupId>
    <artifactId>WIWServer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

 <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Не можете разобраться - не используйте архитипы. Создайте свой `pom.xml` вручную и всё.

Comment: Приведите ваш `pom.xml` и структуру проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Короче, как и писали архитипы мне не пригодились. Долго ковырял файл POM.XML.
Перечитал кучу статтей. Кто только начинает изучать maven вот парочка статтей -
 [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131164/), [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77382/) и [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77333/).

Реально все заработало, после того как последвательно выполнил на новом проекте шаги указанные в следующей статтье (потом просто скопировал pom.xml и исправил ошибки кодировки и добавил зависимости):
https://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-jar-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-maven/

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Pav.Avdonin</groupId>
    <artifactId>PContol</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>PControl</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```